# locally cache amazon s3 codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I have just setup a photo gallery web app which links to my amazon s3 account i have bilt it in code ignitor.

Problem i am having that i am looking for a solution is!

When i pulls the imagess from S3 some of them are 4-5mb which takes forever to load this is really frustrating and i am asking for advice on the best way to handle this.

Is their a way i can cache thumbnail images on the amazon s3 sever or is it best to cache the thumbnails locally on my server and then pull them from their.

Can someone recommend a really good library that i can use in conjunction with code ignitor and s3 to manage this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this I would say upload your images to codeigniter and create some sort of thumbnail script using the [in built Image Manipulation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html) from there you can upload the file to S3 using something like [CloudManiac-Storage over at Codeigniter Sparks](http://getsparks.org/packages/cloudmanic-storage/versions/HEAD/show).

From your description the slowness is only being caused by the long load times on the images, so an upload and thumbnail creation tool is just what you need. As far as I am aware S3 does not come with any sort of built in tool useful for this.

With regards to your question on where is best to cache, S3 is likely to be faster (depending on your hosting setup), however it may cost more. Experiment, work out the costs and see what works best for you personally.